# New company may have lied to me and now I'm in a mess

Tags: job-change

Well, I am working for 2 years in one company, but recently I got an offer from a pretty big company (> 1000 people) to work abroad as a full stack programmer.

I was told that I would be moving the first day of work, and that I can stay there as long as I want to. It's an outsourcing company that hires people and sends them to different clients abroad. The client I was supposed to work for is even bigger corporation.

I agreed on a salary, signed a deal, got ready, told everyone about this - cool. The company has great opinions, everything seemed legit.

But today I got a call from this company that they moved all people from abroad to my country, and that they decided they have too much people. I was told I have thus nothing to do, and I'll be waiting till something gets resolved, while being paid normally. I also got told there's more chance for another project for me, for another client, also abroad, but in different technologies that I don't know and don't want to know.

So I don't know if, and when, I'll be moving abroad (that was the main reason for me to change jobs). I also don't know what I'll be doing after I start the job. I know nothing.

What steps should I take to protect myself?

Comment: It sounds like your CV will be up to date, so, start sending it out. If in the meantime the current company comes through with something that interests you, stay.

Comment: Are you sure they lied? It seems possible they honestly intended to send you abroad, but there was a high level change in plan since the job offer. They are doing their best to minimize the damage to you by paying you to do nothing.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That is a good point, but they won't continue to do that normally at a consultancy company for very long.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to achieve here? You are not getting fired and are still getting paid full salary.

Comment: There's a big difference between "they lied to me" and "their plans changed dramatically".

Comment: I agree with @MisterPositive. They may find work for the OP fairly soon, but the OP should spend the time job hunting and learning additional skills.

Comment: If you're unwilling to learn new technologies, you're going to find working for an outsourcing company very challenging.

Comment: @DavidK he has written he isn't paid full salary. At least not what he considered to be full salary.

Comment: @DanubianSailor, OP states (emphasis mine), "I was told I have thus nothing to do, and I'll be waiting till something gets resolved, **while being paid normally**."

Comment: @DavidK so maybe OP should clarify, I've understood that, that obviously being paid normally means, being paid standard wage, much lower as when working for client. Otherwise, it's quite hard to comprehend what is an issue here. Maybe I was overthinking...

Comment: OP also said the possible future consultancy would be in a language/tool he does not want to work with.

Comment: I'm baffled at why OP doesn't want to know this potential technology. If nothing else, it's another tool for his belt. In an uncertain economy (and they all are), the most important thing is being able to find work and adding this technology may come in handy. Seems rather short-sighted to me

Answer (score 11):

Where you are currently is called being *on the bench*.  This in of itself is not uncommon for short periods of time while the company looks for a suitable placement for you.

It is not normal at all for them to hire you fresh without a suitable position already in place for you to work.  At this point your an expense, that has not brought in the any positive cash flow.

Never mind the fact you were supposed to go abroad, which they may have well intended to do for you at the time discussions occurred, but in business sometimes things change drastically very quickly.

Your situation would make me very uncomfortable, and I would start looking for a new position post haste.

Answer (score 3):

You've learned a hard way you need to **read** your contract instead of **hearing** what the recruiter is saying to you. The best way to protect you in the future is to stick to what is written and not what is promised.

You've said you are working for **outsourcing** company. Your situation looks quite normal for such companies. They produce nothing, they earn money on lending people for companies that need them. Because they have no guarantee they will get some work for people they hire, they like to 'share' risk with their employees via not-so-decent fixed salary paid when 'in-house' and much more better money when you actually work for client. The 2nd one was what was promised to you, the problem is, getting work for client is practically independent from you.

The good news, your company will do everything to get you work for client, because otherwise, even with lower salary, you are the pure cost. The bad news, no guarantee they will success and it's even not dependent on you.

On the other hand, outsourcing **often** means better money, so many people accept that, even if for 2-3 months in year they sit in-house getting half-money or even no-money. In any case, you should always **read contract before signing** so not to be disappointed when not everything is so bright as HRman have said.